# Extract contents of Textarea from HTML to Python

Tags: python, html, django

Well the idea is, I want to create a mailing system in which uses Django. Let's say simply all I have is a URL page, email.html and Django deploys the URL when I enter the correct URL.

The outline of this page is simply a textarea and a submit button. Now, how can I extrapolate the contents in the text area so I can store it in a database to store the contents as well as send the contents to other programs.

I would assume this is possible. Also, I have no models as I have not yet worked on that. So, I am probably doing things in a non-Django fashion. If you have any advance, please I am willing to learn from what you have experienced. I am just unsure how to proceed for this task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the django tutorial, learn how it works and try solving your question yourself. Only then come back if you still face problems

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

Answer (score 0):

I already answered in a comment, but then I figured that you're not a "user(somenumber)" but actually opened an account. So my guess is you're planning to actually keep asking questions in the future and maybe become a programer.

However it is still very obvious you did not do the minimal amount of research or even attempted to solve the problem yourself.

You are asking, in a very convoluted way, to do something extremely simple in django or any web development framework. I'm not gonna tell you how though, because this isn't a tutorial site.

Go to the django documentation. It's really vast and probably the most complete documentation I have ever seen. Do the tutorial. Learn how to create models and templates and how to generate forms.

Then, after you tried and tried, if you still face problems, if you are unsure how to do something **specific**, come back to SO, show us what you tried and I promise you, someone will surely help you.